# How do you refresh System path/variables after installing programs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script which will install an application:

```
os.system("path/to/my.exe /VERYSILENT")
```

When i do this, for example I would install *Git*.

Later on, the application will call:

```
os.system("git --version")
```

which fails to call because it doesnt know what git is.

From what it looks like, the System variables etc are all grabbed when you `import os` so could I just after installing the application reimport os somehow and then carry on?

My desired end state is to refresh CMD, similar to how you would close a terminal and open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-shells (as in `os.system(..)`) cannot effect the execution environment of the parent process (it would be a *huge* security hole).  You can update the permanent user environment with e.g. Powershell (`[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($key, $val, "User")`). Any processes started afterwards will see the new environment variable (this is why you need to close your cmd window and start a new one.

Comment: when installing git, it would install the ability to use git in the command line.  Under normal instances, this is easy, but why not here?  It isnt as easy, but there should be some sort of refresh, or plausibly just adding `import os` to the line after *os.system(...)*

Comment: _Why_ would you think that this would work when installing something in a sub-shell? (remember that environment variables are something you _send_ with the call to start a new process).  It works from the command line since the installer sets the environment variables twice: first it sets the User env variables and then it sets the env var in the current shell.

Comment: `import os` only gets the environment the process was started with, it doesn't get any updates. You could add the `git` directory to `os.environ['path']`

Comment: I understand why a subprocess would act as such.  IF that is the case I would have to do, then is there a way to monitor an application install for changes to user and env variables and then copy them as well into my local scope?  Or would I have to just take a look at each application structure and build my own relative path from the root application directory?

Comment: If you know what you're installing then you can do all sorts of "stuff" like setting the PATH envar in future sub-shells, ie. instead of `os.system(..)` use `supbrocess.Popen(..., env={'PATH':...})` where you include the git install dir in PATH. Or you can probably call `os.setenv()` and it should be inherited in future sub-shells. Or you could write a stub `git.bat` file in a directory (late) on the path that contains `c:\full\path\to\newly\installed\git.exe %*`.  Or you can read the registry and update your version of the environment from the global changes the installer made., etc. etc.